# How to enable HBA in HPE Proliant ML370 G5

Tags: home-server, hardware-raid, hp-proliant, proxmox

I have an HPE Proliant ML370 G5 and want to install Proxmox on it using ZFS but apparently you can only do that if you don't use the RAID controller and instead enable HBA. How can I do that? There's nothing in the user manual

My RAID controller card is HPE Smart Array E200/128 and I want to do RAIDZ-3 in Proxmox